# Scrollby method in selenium

Tags: selenium, scroll

I have used the  below code for scroll down.

`JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
 jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,1250)", "");`

How do you calculate the pixel values when you want to scroll the window to a specific point ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are trying to scroll to some element.
what you can do is:

```
WebElement e = driver.findElement(....);

JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", e);
```